# find duplicate record in Text file

Tags: bash, python, notepad++, awk

I have text file with this kind of structure

```
mv /XXX/20000/XXX-18245 /XXX/20000/XXX-28042
mv /XXX/10000/XXX-9942 /XXX/10000/XXX-18166
mv /XXX/10000/XXX-9962 /XXX/10000/XXX-18189
mv /XXX/20000/XXX-10007 /XXX/20000/XXX-18245
```

I would like to find the duplicate XXX-18245 record in first and fourth rows

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Do you want to **only** identify the duplicate? If so, just double-click on `18245` and both will be highlighted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Notepad++

---

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `XXX-(\d+)[\s\S]+?\K\b\1\b`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Find next</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
XXX-        # literally XXX-
(\d+)       # group 1, 1 or more digits
[\s\S]+?    # 1 or more any character including linebreaks, not greedy
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
\b          # word boundary, make sure to match the exact same number
\1          # backreference to group 1
\b          # word boundary, make sure to match the exact same number
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: @shl_co: Thanks for accepting answer, you can also [vote up](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) ;)

Comment: Can you add what does "Wrap around" do?

Answer (score 0):

In notepad++ you can use a regular expression like below, it'll highlight the whole text from beginning of first match to the end of second one.

- press CTRL+F
- for find what type `(\/XXX[^ ]+)( .*)\1`
- make sure to check both "regular expression" and ". matches newline"
- press "find next"

[image]

Comment: @Junasz Thank you , it look like didn't make the trick [output example](https://ibb.co/dJKQ0DD)

Comment: there should be a space before dot `( .*)` which I can't see in your screenshot

Comment: I can confirm there is space before dot. I shared with you output from example text file I use [output](https://ibb.co/n3RXwDT)

Comment: Your link is broken, would be great if you could include an example in your question

Answer (score 0):

Will you consider using PowerShell? If you don't know how to run PowerShell, press Win+R to bring up Run menu and type PowerShell then Enter, I would recommend pinning PowerShell to taskbar for easy access.
If you are using Linux, just search PowerShell 7.1 and download and install and run, it is foss and cross-platform.

Then, once PowerShell is running(and accepting commands), copy and paste the following code:

```
Get-Content "$txt" | Select-String -Pattern "XXX-18245" -AllMatches | Foreach-Object {$_.Matches}
```

You have to either replace the $txt with the full path of the txt file (to do that, shift+rmb then select copy as path on Windows, if you are using Linux, just ignore this tutorial) or assign the path to the $txt first, by running $txt="path"(use the actual path, not "path", and it has to be enclosed in double quotation marks...
)
Then Press Enter(sorry, but most people don't know how to do all of these)

It should only display lines containing a match(in this case XXX-18245)

The first section gets the content of the file then passes it down the pipeline, the second section reads the result of first section and finds all lines containing a given string, you don't need the third section to make it run, but that would display a lot irrelevant informations, the third section makes the command only display the matching lines.